# Getting grid-row to override grid-template-rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am asking this for my own education, if it is something that is bad practice feel free to say so.

I want elements `#one #two #three` and `#four` to have their parent property  `grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px` overwritten by setting individual grid-row settings to each element.

Elements `#one` and `#two` are responding as I expect when I set them like this:

```
#one{
     grid-row: 1/ span 4 ; 
}

#two{
     grid-row: 1/ span 4 ; 
}
```

However, when I attempt to apply similar settings to `#three` and `#four` I do not get the result I expect. I expect the height of `#three` and `#four` to be exactly the same as `#one` and `#two`. Instead they fly off to the side of the page.

I expected this to display the elements similar to #one and #two. It doesn't work:

```
#three{
     grid-row: 2/ span 4 ; 
}


#four{
     grid-row: 2/ span 4 ; 
}
```

I want to know how to fix this and the correct individual values to set `#three` and `#four` to overwrite grid-template-rows as described.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/ek2r6a19/

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(141, 110, 99);
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}


/*_____________________________GRID */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: purple;
}

#one {
  grid-row: 1/ span 4;
}

#two {
  grid-row: 1/ span 4;
}


/*

I expected this to display the elements similar to #one and #two. It doesn't work
#three{
     grid-row: 2/ span 4 ; 
}


#four{
     grid-row: 2/ span 4 ; 
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">1
    <div class="content-container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    2
    <div class="content-container">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">3
    <div class="content-container">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">4
    <div class="content-container">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="five">5
    <div class="content-container">

      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="six">6
    <div class="content-container">
      text
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the [grid auto-placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo), which calculates the "right" places to render grid areas, when they're not explicitly defined.

You're defining the rows. Just define the columns, as well.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#one {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1; /* new */
}

#two {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 2; /* new */
}

#three {
  grid-row: 2 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1; /* new */
}

#four {
  grid-row: 2 / span 4;
  grid-column: 2; /* new */
}

* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(141, 110, 99);
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">1
    <div class="content-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">2
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">3
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">4
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="five">5
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="six">6
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that `#one` and `#three`, and `#two` and `#four`, don't appear to be the same height. Actually, they are.

The issue is that you've set `#three` and `#four` to start spanning at grid row line 2.

Well, `#one` and `#two` are set to start at grid row line 1, and span 4 rows, so they are overlapping `#three` and `#four` (or vice versa). You would need to start `#three` and `#four` at grid row line 5.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* added to accommodate more rows */
}

#one {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#two {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 2;
}

#three {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#four {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 2;
}

* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(141, 110, 99);
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">1
    <div class="content-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">2
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">3
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">4
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="five">5
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="six">6
    <div class="content-container">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```